# Selenium xpath Webelement issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am a bit new to selenium so pardon my ignorance.
I am trying get rows of an ajax loaded table from a website.
The code looks something like this:

```
try:
    table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tableid")))

finally :
    
    for row in table.xpath(".//tr"):
        print(row)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

Let me know what the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

...implies that your program have attempted to invoke an attribute `xpath` which isn't available.

---

### Solution

[WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) have no attribute as `xpath`. Instead you may like to invoke `find_element_by_xpath()` method. So effectively you have to change the line:

```
for row in table.xpath(".//tr"):
```

with:

```
for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath("./tr"):
```

Comment: Hi this is not working for `./tr` i am getting error **no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./tr"}**

Comment: @kiteshjain Fixed a minor bug, retest and let me know the status.